# MobX application is reloading

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I am using Mobx as datastore.
Code is as below.

channelStore - contains @observable channels[], @action addChannel(chan)

channel.js component has a form when submitted is calling channelStore.addChannel().

I see that it is successfully adding data to channelStore as it is reflecting in UI, however immediately the app is refreshing and added channel is no longer available.

No clue why!!!

My App is created as below.
`create-react-app > eject > install babel plugin transform-decorators-legacy ("^1.3.4") > npm init > npm start`

src/datastore/channelstore.js

```
import { observable, computed, action, extendObservable } from 'mobx';

class ChannelStore{
    @observable activeChannel = 'hello';
    @observable activeUser = 'anon';
    @observable channels = ['hello'];
    @observable users = [];
    @observable connected = false;

    @action setActiveChannel(channel){
        this.activeChannel = channel;
    }

    @action setActiveUser(user){
        this.activeUser = user;
    }

    @action addChannel(chan){
        console.log('Adding Channel '+chan)
        this.channels.push(chan)
        //this.channels[0] = chan;
    }

    @action addUser(user){
        this.users.push(user)
    }

    @action setConnectionStatus(status){
        this.connected = status;
    }
}

let channelStore = new ChannelStore()
export default channelStore;
```

src/components/channel.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';

@inject('channelStore')     
@observer
class Channel extends Component {

    render() {
        const { channelStore } = this.props;
        const channels = channelStore.channels;
        const activeChannel = channelStore.activeChannel;

        console.log(channels);

        return (
            <div className=' panel panel-primary'>
                <div className='panel-heading'>
                    <strong>Channels</strong>
                </div>
                <div className='panel-body channels'>
                {
                    channels.map((chan, i)=>{
                        return (
                        <a key={i} onClick={(e)=>channelStore.setActiveChannel(chan)}>
                        {
                            (chan === activeChannel) ?
                                <li key={i} className='active'>{chan}</li>
                            :
                                <li key={i}>{chan}</li>
                        }
                        </a>
                        )
                    })
                }
                <form onSubmit={(e)=>channelStore.addChannel(this.refs.channelInput.value)}>
                    <div className='form-group'>
                        <input 
                            type='text' 
                            ref='channelInput'
                            className='form-control'
                            placeholder='Add Channel'
                        />
                    </div>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Channel
```

src/App.js

```
import { Provider } from "mobx-react";
import channelStore from './datastore/channelstore';
import Channels from './components/channel';

..
 <Provider channelStore={channelStore}>
            <div className="app">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-4">
                            <Channels />
                            <Users />
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-md-8">
                            <MessageBox />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Provider>
```

Comment: Figured out my problem. i am missing `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your comment and since your anchor `<a>` element has no `href` tag i think your talking about `onSubmit` on the form.

`onSubmit` is called by the browser before submitting the form to the server (to the url defined in `action` attribute and http method defined in `method` attribute.

You can prevent the form submitting to server (and reloading the page) by calling `preventDefault()` on the event object given to the event listener.

Best practise is to do this as first action in your listener. because if there is something that throws an exception `preventDefault()` wont be called (if it is further down the function) and thus the form will submit and the page will reload.

### another solution

another solution would be to not trigger submit at all, but on button click manually handle save action. So than make sure there is no Submit button.